# Existence condition of solution for a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, interval-arithmetic

I have the following system of nonlinear equations:

$$\left\{
\begin{align}
& \dfrac{-a}{w^2}\sin(wT) + \dfrac{T}{w}[a\cos(wT) - b\sin(wT)] + c = 0 \\
& \dfrac{b}{w}\sin(wT) + T[a\sin(wT) + b\cos(wT)] = 0 \\
& \int_{0}^{T}{h(a,b,c,w,t)dt} = 0 \\
& \sin(c+w) - w\cos(c+w) - c = 0\\
& \sin{c} - \int_{0}^{T}{h(a,b,c,w,t)tdt} = X, \text{ where}\\
\end{align}
\right.
$$

- $X$ is a given positive number.
- $a,b,c,w,T$ are real variables.
- $h(a,b,c,w,t)$ is a highly complicated function with many trigonometric terms.

For each $X$, I have tried to numerically solve this system of nonlinear equations by MATLAB and I always found a solution of $(a,b,c,w,T)$.

**My concern is: I would like to prove the *existence of solution* for the above set of nonlinear equations for any value of $X$. Do you know what mathematical tools can we use for that purpose?**

I very much appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on $h$.

For example, if $h(a,b,c,w,t)>0$, then $T=0$ and if $X\neq 0$ there isn't a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @dcolazin. So what I meant is that: is there any general method or computational technique that can conclude the solution existence when we know the bound of $X$ and the given function $h(a,b,c,w,t)$?